# Even with bounty, I do not get much attention

Tags: feature-request

I have a question about my Software Recommendations Stack Exchange post: [What is the best alternative to SwiftUI for MacOS?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/72002/what-is-the-best-alternative-to-swiftui-for-macos)

Even with a 100 rep bounty, there is still, no comments, or no attempts to answer. I think this site should be better advertised within SE. In fact, a lot of SO questions are closed as off topic, and instead of saying, closed as off topic for being a software recommendation, how about we site the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), so this site can get more attention, AND such questions can get answered. Two birds with one stone, lol.

Comment: I am the person who posted this

Comment: And in fact, so far 2 subsequent 100 rep bounties, nothing

Answer (score 3):

That's true, we need more visitors, and especially more people who can answer questions.

When I see recommendation questions getting closed on StackOverflow, I always encourage askers to ask at SR. This does not automatically get us more answerers, though.

All initiatives to advertise SR are welcome :-)

[Community ads](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5155/community-promotion-ads-2019) might be an option, they seem to be late this year though.

Answer (score 0):

> closed as off topic for being a software recommendation, how about we site the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, so this site can get more attention, AND such questions can get answered. Two birds with one stone, lol.

100% agreed, 2 issues:

1. The majority of close voters on SO don't seem to care about other SE websites.
2. Old questions posted on SO cannot be migrated. This makes no sense.